# What are the best practices to manage an ExecutorService in a library?

Tags: java, threadpool, shutdown-hook

In one of my libraries, I use a fixed thread pool executor with 5 threads; my threads are not heavyweight, I `.get()` with timeouts, but as to the `ExecutorService`, I create it and after that, this is "live and let die".

You are supposed to `.shutdown{,Now}()` it when you're done with it; but this being a library, I cannot know in advance how it will be used: with a simple `main()`, in a webapp which will be managed by the servlet container, others.

This doesn't feel right. How do I do better? Should I just be using something else than an `ExecutorService`?

**EDIT** link to the only user: [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/msg-simple/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/provider/LoadingMessageSourceProvider.java); daemon threads may be a solution, now I don't know if they have drawbacks I should be aware of...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement thread pool that will automatically shutdown at end of execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769429/how-to-implement-thread-pool-that-will-automatically-shutdown-at-end-of-executio)

Comment: IMO, it is on the client (your API caller) to shut down the service as your lib is **stateful**. Of course, daemon threads could solve some of the problems, but this might not be what you want as they automagically die after all non-daemon threads have been stopped. Is it possible to share the interface to your lib?

Comment: @home link to the only class using it: [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/msg-simple/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/provider/LoadingMessageSourceProvider.java). The "user side" class, `MessageBundle`, can be `private static final` -- in fact I always use it this way

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not really an answer, more like an idea...

As I already mentioned in my earlier comment, your `LoadingMessageSourceProvider` component maintains state, so someone must be responsible to properly shutdown the component. You could try to implement this as part of the component by registering a [shutdown hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950396/contextdestroyed-vs-addshutdownhook) (I won't consider `finalize` here :-).

I'd rather leave it to your components' user (application), as it better knows when to shutdown. In fact you're implementing a lightweight container having a lifecycle - in some way  similar to a Java EE 7 container provider implementing [JSR-236](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/concurrency-1_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

Given that you don't have a JSR-236 container available, you must enable the caller to manage lifecycle. I could think of a factory approach, simplified example:

```
// maintains the executor service (one service per factory)
private MessageSourceProviderFactory f = MessageSourceProviderFactory.instance();

private void stuff() {
    MessageSourceProvider msp = f.newBuilder()/*. [...] */.build();
    // work with the provider
}

// at some point in time the caller decides to finish
private void end() {
    f.shutdown(); // shutdown the factory and the ExecutorService
}
```

JSR-236 section 3.1.6.1 is fairly interesting in terms of lifecycle:

> 3.1.6.1 Java EE Product Provider Requirements  This subsection describes additional requirements for ManagedExecutorService
> providers.
>
> 1. All tasks, when executed from the ManagedExecutorService, will run with the Java EE component  identity of the component that submitted
>    the task.
> 2. The lifecycle of a ManagedExecutorService is managed by an application server. All lifecycle operations  on the
>    ManagedExecutorService interface will throw a
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException exception.  This includes the
>    following methods that are defined in the
>    java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService interface: awaitTermination(),
>    isShutdown(), isTerminated(), shutdown(), and shutdownNow().Final
>    Release 3-11
> 3. No task submitted to an executor can run if task’s component is not started.
>
> When a ManagedExecutorService instance is being shutdown by
> the Java EE Product Provider:
>
> 1. All attempts to submit new tasks are rejected.
> 2. All submitted tasks are cancelled if not running.
> 3. All running task threads are interrupted.
> 4. All registered ManagedTaskListeners are invoked